# What is the function of というのは in this sentence?

Tags: particles

その場面というのはどういった場面かというと、ナチスの兵士がですね、ユダヤ人を職業別で分けていきます。

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xs-XWk_oQA 0:55

Translation from subtitles: There’s a scene where the Nazi’s are separating the Jewish by their occupation.

I'm wondering if と言うのは here could have some meaning that extends from と言う such as "as for (said) scene..." or "as for the (previously mentioned) scene..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 'というのは' it talks about what you said earlier and after that the speaker trying to explain the definition of that or giving explanation for that.
roughly it can be translated as,
When you say that screen what it means is...

Comment: I would translate 場面 in this context as "scene".