# 私たちはよく「みんな持っているから」とか「みんなもそう言っている」なんていう言い方をしますね。

Tags: meaning

> 私たちはよく「みんな持っているから」とか「みんなもそう言っている」なんていう言い方をしますね。しかし、実際には「みんな」というのは自分の周りの二、三人だったということがよくあります。私たちは「みんな」という言葉を簡単に使い過ぎていると思います。言葉はもう少し正しく使うようにしたほうがいいのではないでしょうか。

I am having trouble understanding what the なんていう言い方をしますね. Does the いう in this phrase mean talk/say? If so why is there another one right after it?

Comment: Yeah, this is confusing. Meanwhile these questions and answers may help you https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34320/why-is-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86-in-%e3%83%9c%e3%82%bd%e3%83%8b%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e9%a3%9f%e3%81%b9%e7%89%a9-for-example-written-in-%e3%81%b2%e3%82%89%e3%81%8c%e3%81%aa-rather-than-%e3%81%a8%e8%a8%80%e3%81%86 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33503/what-is-the-function-of-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%ae%e3%81%af-in-this-sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first いう is originally 言う, but this ていう/という is almost a fixed particle used to join two phrases and make the first modify the second. AというB is "B called A", "B known as A", "B of A", "B that is A", etc. Since it's a function word rather than an ordinary verb, it's almost always written in hiragana. The second 言う is literally "say".

- 消防士という仕事
  the job known as firefighter
- リーダーを補佐するという役割
  the role of supporting the leader
- 彼が試験に合格したというニュース
  news that that he passed the exam
- "comprised of" という言い方をする
  to use the expression "comprised of"

> 私たちはよく「みんな持っているから」とか「みんなもそう言っている」なんていう言い方をしますね。
>
> We often use such a phrase as "Because everyone else has it" or "Everyone says so", right?